# if else error message always shows else statement message

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I think this is a simple problem. But, I don't know how to solve this problem. I have posted my codes below. Here, In this below code if else statement always shows `No Sarees`. I got the result from mysql table but it always shows with `No Sarees` text. I have checked this using `var_dump($categories)` it returns `array(0){}` . How can I solve this problem?

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <!--BOF Refine Search Result-->
    <div class="refine-search-result">
        <?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>

            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                <div class="refine-block">
                    <p><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></p>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($categories);) { ?>
                <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($categories) / 4); ?>
                <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
                    <?php if (isset($categories[$i])) { ?>
                        <div class="refine-block">
                            <p><a href="<?php echo $categories[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $categories[$i]['name']; ?></a></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--EOF Refine Search Result-->
<?php } else {
    ?>
    <div class="refine-search-result">
        <div class="refine-block">
            <p><a href="javascript://" style="cursor:default">No Sarees</a></p>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are showing the wrong code! We need to see how $categories is populated, probably further up in the file

Comment: You do realize that you don't need to *OPEN* and *CLOSE* every single line with `<?php ... ?>` right?

Comment: Are you sure `$categories` has values in it and is initialized? I think your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to

Comment: How to fill value in $categories? please check it

Answer (score 0):

If your `$categories` is empty array then in `if($categories)` your array is converted to boolean value. If it's empty array (and you say it is) then it's get converted to `false`.

Check this:

```
$categories = array();  //empty array

var_dump((boolean)$categories); //this will show what variable will look like after converting to boolean value

if ($categories){
  echo '$categories IS NOT empty';
}else{
  echo '$categories IS empty';
}
```